# How do I fit labels into a Tkinter frame and canvas with scrollbar functionality?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a list of letters that can be checked, but when the list goes off the window I don't know how to get the scrollbar to work. I have read that you need to put the labels into a frame and then into a canvas, but that is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
NORMAL_FONT = ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT = ("Verdana", 8)

number_of_rows = 20

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = tk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORMAL_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()



class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    master_frame = tk.Frame(self)
    container = tk.Canvas(master_frame, height=300, width=720, scrollregion=(0,0,300,720))

    master_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    vbar = tk.Scrollbar(container,orient="vertical")
    vbar.grid(column=1, sticky="ns")
    vbar.config(command=container.yview)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(-0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(-0, weight=1)

    container.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    #container.create_window(0,0,window=master_frame, anchor='nw')

    child_to_container_frame = tk.Frame(container)
    child_to_container_frame.grid_rowconfigure(-0, weight=1)
    child_to_container_frame.grid_columnconfigure(-0, weight=1)


    self.frames = {}

    menubar = tk.Menu(master_frame)
    filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Help", command = lambda: popupmsg("Not supported yet"))
    filemenu.add_separator()
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    optionmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    optionmenu.add_command(label="Option #1", command = lambda: popupmsg("You clicked option #1"))
    optionmenu.add_command(label="Option #2", command = lambda: popupmsg("You clicked option #2"))
    optionmenu.add_command(label="Option #3", command = lambda: popupmsg("You clicked option #3"))
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=optionmenu)
    menubar.add_command(label="Start", command = lambda: popupmsg("Starting Scan"))

    tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

    frame = StartPage(child_to_container_frame, self)
    self.frames[StartPage] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame(StartPage)



    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.PlaceLabels()

    def PlaceLabels(self):
        self.row = []
        self.checkboxrow = []
        self.text_in_row = []
        self.states = []
        letter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"]
        for i in range(number_of_rows):
            self.states.append(tk.IntVar())
            self.row.append(tk.Label(self, bg="white", pady=5, font=(None, 1), height=20, width=720))
            self.row[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=3, pady=5)
            self.checkboxrow.append(tk.Checkbutton(self, bg="white", variable=self.states[i], command= lambda: self.DarkenLabel()))
            self.checkboxrow[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10)
            self.text_in_row.append(tk.Label(self, bg="white", text=letter[i]))
            self.text_in_row[i].grid(row=i, column=0)

    def DarkenLabel(self):
        for i in range(len(self.checkboxrow)):
            if self.states[i].get() == 1:
                self.row[i].config(bg="gray")
                self.checkboxrow[i].config(bg="gray")
                self.text_in_row[i].config(bg="gray")
            else:
                self.row[i].config(bg="white")
                self.checkboxrow[i].config(bg="white")
                self.text_in_row[i].config(bg="white")                


app = Window()
app.geometry('733x500')
app.mainloop()
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the beginning of the Windows class, but I don't know.

I have tried:
`container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)`
and
`container.create_window(0,0,window=master_frame, anchor='nw')`
but both didn't work for me.

Any advice?
And thank you for your help

Comment: The first step is to remove everything from your code except for one canvas, one frame, and the labels. Since you are having difficulty in understanding the code, the less code there is, the easier it will be to understand. Once you do that, and understand how to make the simple case work, then you can solve the problem of integrating it back with your  program. You can keep `StartPage`, but remove almost everything else but the imports, a root window, and the last three lines,

Comment: Okay I'll try that thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Bryan Oakley's advice from his comment and it really helped me solve this problem. Here is the code I have, with just the bare bones:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        master_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        master_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        vbar = tk.Scrollbar(master_frame)
        vbar.pack(side='right',fill="y")

        container = tk.Canvas(master_frame, height=300, width=720, scrollregion=(0,0,300,720))                
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        child_to_container_frame = tk.Frame(container)
        container.create_window(0,0,window=child_to_container_frame, anchor='nw')        

        vbar.config(command=container.yview)
        container.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set, scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1500))

        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(child_to_container_frame, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.row = []
        self.row.append(tk.Label(self, bg="white", pady=5, font=(None, 1), height=20, width=720))
        self.row[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=3, pady=5)        


app = Window()
app.geometry('733x500')
app.mainloop()
```